# Fast bivariate smoother?

Tags: nonparametric, smoothing

I need a nonparametric regression for two explanatory variables that is faster than GAM.

```
lm = gam(X3 ~ s(X1,X2,k=8),data=dataset)
```

If the sample size is about 125,000, it took 21 seconds on my laptop (Windows 7, CPU: i5 @1.7GHz)

Is there any smoothing method that is much faster than this?
Or I wonder if there is any option that makes the gam command run faster.

Comment: Is this data on a dense regular grid or not?

Comment: @usεr11852  No, it is not.

Comment: Effectively you have three choices: 1. Splines (semi-parametric basis), 2. 2-D Wavelets/Fourier/Cosines decomposition (parametric basis) , 3. Bivariate local (linear/quadratic/etc.) regression (fully non-parametric). If speed is an issue, you need to go to parametric. (Sorry just saw your comment.) Cont.

Comment: Based on the fact you have irregular data, I think you are close to your best solution. Experiment a bit with the spline families provided in gam. Also check `mgcv::bam`; 100k+ qualifies as a very large dataset.